# Optimal way to index a list of numbers

Tags: algorithm

Given a list of non-sequential and unordered numbers is there an optimal means to index the list, where the ith element in the index is the position of the ith element in the indexed list if it were sorted.

So [45,2,6,33] would have index [4,1,2,3]

Comment: Nick it would be nice if you shared your attempts/approaches to this problem. =)

Comment: I would sort the inputs. If inputs are very small use counting sort. If they are large , use quick sort

Comment: Are the numbers unique, or can there be multiple occurances of a number in the array?

Comment: simply radix sorting and using a hashmap to store position won't work? What's your required time/space complexity?

Answer (score 0):

You can just sort the list and then create a dictionary / associative array mapping each element to its index in the sorted list. You could do this in a loop, or, in Python, even in a single line:

```
>>> lst = [45, 2, 6, 33]
>>> d = {x: i for (i, x) in enumerate(sorted(lst))}
>>> d
{2: 0, 6: 1, 33: 2, 45: 3}
```

Now use the values from the dictionary to create your result list:

```
>>> [d[x] + 1 for x in lst]
[4, 1, 2, 3]
```

---

If the list can contain duplicate numbers, and you don't want your result list to contain duplicate indices, you can map the values to lists of indices:

```
>>> lst = [45, 2, 6, 33, 6]
>>> d = {}
>>> for i, x in enumerate(sorted(lst)):
...     d.setdefault(x, []).append(i)
>>> d
{2: [0], 6: [1, 2], 33: [3], 45: [4]}
```

Now, convert each of those lists to an iterator, and get the next index for each value in the original list.

```
>>> d2 = {x: iter(d[x]) for x in d}
>>> [next(d2[x]) + 1 for x in lst]
[5, 1, 2, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform radix sort which uses counting sort as a sub-routine and can work in linear time complexity for large numbers as well. Time complexity will be `O(n)`.

Then use a hashmap `<element, position when sorted>` to record the position of the elements in sorted list. At last print the corresponding position of input. Space complexity is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem you are facing is that how to keep the original position of element since after sorting the position would be lost. You need to link position in original array with the element and then sort. Following is the pseudo code

```
list of pair p[] as (element, original position)
for each index i in original input array A
    p.push(A[i], i) //adding element and original position
```

Sort on basis of first element

```
q = sort(p)
```

Now q has element in its position after sorting. Second array should have this position on its index in original array

Let new array B is resultant array

```
for each index i in array q
    B[q[i].second] = i //q[i].second is index in original array. so putting index of sorted array in that
```

Update: Some are not able to understand this algorithm so have put a code in JavaScript.

```js
var input = [45,2,6,33];

var p = [];

for(var i = 0;i < input.length;i++)
{
  p.push({first:input[i],second:i});
}

p.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.first > b.first;
});

var B = Array(input.length);

for(var i = 0;i < p.length;i++)
{
  B[p[i].second] = i;
}

console.log(B);
```

Comment: You are right, I misunderstood the last part of the algorithm.